# Android AppCompat AlertDialog styling with theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-styles

I wish to be able to set a theme to set the **message** text size in an AppCompat AlertDialog. The theme needs to have `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"`. I have spent hours searching and trying all the suggestions, but none of them seem to work with that base theme.

If the parent is changed to the Holo theme, then I can alter the message text size using `textAppearanceMedium`, but the rest of the dialog looks really ugly :S

Currently my theme is (all this is currently hooked up and working):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- Button text size -->
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/ui_text_size</item>
    <!-- Content text color -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/ui_text_color</item>
    <!-- Title style -->
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyDialogTitleStyle</item>
    <!-- Button style (except size) -->
    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/MyDialogButtonTextAppearance</item>
    <!-- Dialog background -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/ui_background</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyDialogTitleStyle" parent="@style/RtlOverlay.DialogWindowTitle.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyDialogTitleTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/ui_large_text_size</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyDialogTitleTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/ui_large_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ui_title_color</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyDialogButtonTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: You can also create a custom Dialog.

Comment: Can you post screenshots with both material theme and holo theme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like there is no way to this via a theme attribute. Let's look at the source code of [appcompat-v7 library](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_material.xml). Following the `TextView` that reflects the message of the `AlertDialog`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AlertDialogLayout ... >

    <!-- ... -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@android:id/message"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
                    android:paddingRight="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"/>

    <!-- ... -->

</android.support.v7.widget.AlertDialogLayout>
```

As you can see the `TextView` uses the `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead` as the style. Following its definition:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"/>
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_subhead_material</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

The `textSize` is static and isn't resolved via an attribute like the `textColor` (which uses the `textColorPrimary`). Thus there's no option for us to set the textSize. The only way to do it would be to override the `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead` style by adding it to your own `styles.xml` file and set the `textSize` to whatever value you need. But be aware there may be side effects since this style can be used in other places as well.

#### tl;dr

Options:

1. Define  `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead` in your styles.xml file and override the `textSize` attribute.
2. Do it programatically (find `TextView` by id and #setTextSize)
3. Use your own layout in the dialog - the source code of appcompat-v7 may be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks @reVerse, defining my own `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead` worked a treat!